# Dojo AMD style templates for EnhancedGrid Filter plugin

Tags: dojo, dojo-build

I have an Enhanced grid with Filter plugin as shown below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>


    <style type="text/css">@import "./dojo/resources/dojo.css";
@import "./dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/claro/EnhancedGrid.css";
@import "./dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/EnhancedGrid_rtl.css";

/*Grid need a explicit width/height by default*/
#grid {
    width: 45em;
    height: 20em;
}</style>
<script data-dojo-config="async: true" src='./dojo/dojo.js'></script>
<script data-dojo-config="async: true" src='./dojo/mydojo.js'></script>
<script>
```

```javascript
var dojoConfig = {
    baseUrl: "./",
    tlmSiblingOfDojo: false,
    packages: [
        { name: "dojo", location: "dojo" },
        { name: "dijit", location: "dijit" },
        { name: "dojox", location: "dojox" }
    ]
};
```

```javascript
require(["dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid","dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore",
"dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Filter"], 
function(EnhancedGrid,ItemFileWriteStore,Filter){
        /*set up data store*/
        var data = {
          identifier: 'id',
          items: []
        };
        var data_list = [
          { col1: "normal", col2: false, 
col3: 'But are not followed by two hexadecimal', col4: 29.91},
          { col1: "important", col2: false,
 col3: 'Because a % sign always indicates', col4: 9.33},
          { col1: "important", col2: false, 
col3: 'Signs can be selectively', col4: 19.34}
        ];
        var rows = 60;
        for(var i=0, l=data_list.length; i<rows; i++){
          data.items.push(dojo.mixin({ id: i+1 }, data_list[i%l]));
        }
        var store = ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});

        /*set up layout*/
        var layout = [[
          {'name': 'Column 1', 'field': 'id'},
          {'name': 'Column 2', 'field': 'col2'},
          {'name': 'Column 3', 'field': 'col3', 'width': '230px'},
          {'name': 'Column 4', 'field': 'col4', 'width': '230px'}
    ]];

        /*create a new grid:*/
        var grid = EnhancedGrid({
            id: 'grid',
            store: store,
            structure: layout,
            rowSelector: '20px',
                plugins: {
                   filter: {
                    closeFilterbarButton: true,
                    ruleCount: 5,
                    itemsName: "songs"
                   }
                }
         },  "gridDiv");

        /*append the new grid to the div*/
       // dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid.domNode);

        /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
    grid.startup();
    //alert("ee");
    //grid.placeAt("gridDiv");
});

</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<div id="gridDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I invoke the above HTML, I see a number of html files related to Filter plugin being downloaded which include:

```
/dojox/grid/enhanced/templates/FilterBar.html
/dojox/grid/enhanced/templates/FilterDefPane.html
/dojox/grid/enhanced/templates/CriteriaBox.html
/dojox/grid/enhanced/templates/FilterBoolValueBox.html
```

I want these files to become part of the EnhancedGrid's Javascript. So far I have found the following solution:

http://grokbase.com/t/dojo/dojo-interest/11bs5jf64d/custom-build-including-css-and-html-files

But I am unable to get how to use the code by Kallenboone in the above link.

Could someone help pls.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following link on how to create builds for dojo:

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/build/